# Learning how to do DC and AC operating point biasing for a single transistor amplifier circuitry

Tags: amplifier

I am trying to learn how to do proper DC and AC operating point biasing for a simple transistor amplifier circuitry before I attempt to debug https://github.com/promach/frequency_trap. Could anyone guide me ?

The output conductance angle for this class-c amplifier is not right at all. WHY ?

[image]

**Why does the voltage-across-Cb or v(vin, vbase) varies sinusoidally around 85mV ?  Note: i(v_ip1) is the collector current**

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJIU9T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Well that one is correctly biassed, if you were aiming for Class C operation, though it has no gain at DC and a DC input. Start by defining what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean with "..ac operating point"?

Comment: I should say LC tank tuning instead of AC operating point

Comment: What is the purpose of the 1k resistor? Do you know HOW to bias a transistor and - more than that - what "biasing" means?

Comment: My circuitry is based on signal-biasing as in http://www.daenotes.com/electronics/communication-system/class-c-amplifier-operation

Rb creates negative voltage across it, so that it could turn the transistor OFF

This is why this class C output conductance angle is less than usual

Comment: what did you expect?  What did you measure? When did you measure after steady state with RC=1ms !!

Comment: Did you compute the correct f or sweep it slowly

Comment: The initial turn on may reach several Amps base current from Vbe=1vp

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit is a pulsed sine wave from the negative bias and saturates the collector hard, so it acts like a switched diode rather than a linear amplifier.

A CE amp is high impedance  with no R load LC will have very high Q >>100. But when driven by a low impedance switch, has a very low Q.  The result is the average of these two Q resonant load conditions.

Neither a voltage source nor a current source but a switched current source determined by input bias and signal voltage. With a large time constant on the input cap the base will act as a positive clamp and the average DC voltage thus reducing the conduction time.  Then at resonance the output saturates hard again and increases input current and LC current theoretically rises to 37A with an ideal transistor with hFE=100 just below 15.6MHz

You would likely achieve greater than Q=100 with a 10 Ohm load becuase of DCR and ESR of L,C parts and your AC source has ZERO impedance, driving Vbe into excessive Ibe.

You can play with it [here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%205e-9%2038.696464541249114%2051%205%2053%0Aw%20240%2096%20288%2096%200%0Ar%20240%20240%20240%20208%200%201000%0At%20240%20208%20336%20208%200%201%20-3.009290828475457%20-1.0912185077851149%20100%0Ag%20336%20224%20336%20256%200%0AR%20240%2096%20192%2096%200%200%2040%203.3%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20448%2096%20448%20160%200%2010%0Ac%20240%20208%20192%20208%200%201.0000000000000001e-7%20-0.16196954969687916%0AO%20448%20160%20496%20160%200%0Ag%20240%20240%20240%20256%200%0Al%20336%2096%20336%20160%200%201e-9%20-22.861676240108125%0Ac%20288%2096%20288%20160%200%201e-7%201.3819276793096578%0A170%20144%20208%20112%20208%203%2015000000%2016000000%201%200.001%0Aw%20288%2096%20336%2096%200%0Aw%20336%2096%20416%2096%200%0Aw%20288%20160%20336%20160%200%0Aw%20336%20160%20336%20192%200%0Aw%20448%20160%20336%20160%200%0As%20416%2096%20448%2096%200%201%20false%0Ar%20400%2096%20400%20160%200%2010000%0Aw%20400%20160%20448%20160%200%0Aw%20400%2096%20416%2096%200%0Ax%2067%20174%20280%20177%204%2014%2015M%7E17MHz%5Cslog%5Cssweep%5Cs2Vpp%5Cs1ms%0Ar%20144%20208%20192%20208%200%2050%0Ao%2011%2064%200%204353%200.15625%200.0125%200%202%2011%203%0Ao%207%2064%200%204354%2010%200.1%201%201%0Ao%209%2064%200%204353%205%2051.2%202%202%209%203%0Ao%2010%2064%200%204354%205%201.6%202%202%2010%203%0A)
[image]

When you compute LC resonance , look at the Impedance and understand why Inductor I/ Cap V is always 10 here.

[image]

Above changing sampling time Options>Other options> from 5n to 5p (s)

Comment: I am referring to 'out' simulated waveform in falstad.  Am I supposed to expect full conductance angle for class C amplifier ?

Comment: No, you can choose a faster sweep? and see for your self > select Q then  View in Scope then choose Ic and see it goes to 0 mA

Comment: Thanks for the transient simulation advice. I also got the similar conduction angle in ngspice as in https://i.imgur.com/rTF4vB3.png .  I am quite confused about the AC analysis result that I got though.

https://i.imgur.com/L0xb5LE.png

Comment: What's confusing ? Zc(f) =0.1 ohms RL=10 Q=100 , BW>=160kHz, envelope rise time is 0.35/BW~2ms which matches your plot , I show Ic=152mA pk pulse for 10% of a cycle  and meanwhile LC current is >2A with 400mVpp into 10 Ohms

Comment: Since you are not conducting 90% of the time, it just rings when you sweep it fast, so a very slow sweep is needed depending on Q

Comment: I am okay with conduction angle. I am confused with AC analysis result that I got at https://i.imgur.com/L0xb5LE.png

Comment: According to http://whites.sdsmt.edu/classes/ee322/class_notes/322Lecture22.pdf#page=9 , we cannot use the small signal model of transistor due to non-linearity issue. Is that true, Tony ?

Comment: Yes , once Vce <2V, , hFE drops to about 10% of max at =Vce(sat) ( as defined in datasheet by Ic/Ib=10)

Comment: kevin your flat line looks dead, but you have to figure out what you did wrong and compare with what I did right. MHz/ms must not exceed  bandwidth of LC by some margin.  You can also use 1/3f and get harmonic distortion gain and aliasing effects sweeping 15~17MHz  due to mixing action of pulse switch and BPF oscillation

Comment: Tony, the flat line you saw is AC analysis. AC analysis is not suitable for non-linear circuit such as Class-C amplifier.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: probably, although I dont use Spice anymore for what you did.  there is no mention of time scale or DC bias condition for the narrow band plot , so ambiguous.

Comment: perhaps if Rb was pulled up with 10k instead you might get something

Comment: I am planning to a pss spice analysis since conventional AC analysis does not work for non-linear circuit like Class C amplfiier.

Any comments ?